# Strange Token Sale on Uniswap - Need Help Understanding

Tags: erc-20, uniswap

I found a weird issue with a new token on Uniswap. The total supply is 690 billion, and 660 billion went into a Uniswap pool. The creator gave up control.

Now, here's the odd part: someone sold over 55 trillion tokens! That's way more than what exists. What's even stranger is the selling address didn't buy any tokens or get them from the creator.

Links:

Token Contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x413730eb1e051814bcab9b175a54a8f1d32ebc68
Creator's Address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x394fa289ee00e9ec1dd9ddffac41c7facb64bfce
Strange Token Sale Transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5ff8f19a95f1ec3ab8028a406ab136b2d15dd54e2f6ee4819d63814c9109f340
Any ideas on how this massive token sale happened without the creator being involved or any purchase records from the selling address? Thanks for your help!